# What is the most secure way to add an account login + HWID lock to a Java program?

Tags: java, mysql

So I have a Java Program that just runs in the windows console at the moment. When the program first starts, I want to have it go through a login prompt with a username & password. I’ve previously used a MySQL database to check if a username + password combo exists, and then allow that user to login. I know how to encrypt passwords and such when I compare them to the database info. However, when I did this, the MySQL login details were left in the code so that the program could connect to the database. This leaves a huge problem in that someone could decompile the program and find those login details, then use them to access the database.

So my question is, is there a way to access these logins using the program, WITHOUT exposing my database details to a snooping person. Is there a library out there that could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do it, But you need to re-architect your application.
You should separate you application into two different application.(In short: *you have long way to go*)

**1- Client Application**: Where your Java Application is interacting with the end user.

**2- Server Application:** Where your Application is interacting with your DataBase. This Application can talk to your Client through your network.

***Note: keep in mind that, any application at client, can be decompiled. All traffic even any communication between client-server can be monitored.***

There are many methods out there, to make the communication between the server and clients. The choice is yours, you can make your own one (Socket communication) or follow some standards like REST or SOAP.

If you want to use REST or SOAP, there are many ready framework and libraries available where **[Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework)** is one of them. Since you need to have Server Application(Ex: Rest Server), you need to run your server application in a container, where in this case, **[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)** is the most famous one in JAVA world.

**But there is better way to Start** ; you can make an **[Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot)** Application for your Server app. Most of the libraries even your container is already embedded, and you only need to focus in your Application Logic. Once it's done, you just need to run a single jar file and your client can start talk to the server app, through network. The drawback is that you need to follow the spring boot standard.

You can also Secure your Rest API by **[Spring Security framework](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security)** (Which is totally separate topic), but you can simplify it to, **token exchange** between your server-client for each REST call.

So in this scenario, let say someone decompile your client application, he would
see nothing but, some rest API links, which can not work without login and token.

Also keep in mid that you also need to Secure the communication between Server and Client Throw the Network by **[TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)**.(Which is totally separate topic)

Answer (score 0):

If you're giving out db access then deal with the side effects of that choice. I think mysql offers some kind of row level security option. Check the docs.

If you want some level of backend obfuscation then put it between your users and backend via REST or some other scheme.

Comment: I'm assuming that REST would be the better way to go in this situation?

Comment: We write our best code when we stick to conventions we're most familiar with.